# How to Dynamically Update the Values of a 'select-chosen' class Drop down on the Base of Other 'select-chosen' Drop down?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen, prototype-chosen

I have two drop downs. If I don't use the `select-chosen` class and use them simply as `form-control` class, their HTML is simple and I can change the values of the 2nd drop down by sending the AJAX request based on the value of 1st drop down as given in below code snippet:

```
<select id="firsttDropDown" class='form-control'>
    <option value='1'>Value 1</option>
</select>

<select id="secondDropDown" class='form-control'>
    <option value='2'>Value 2</option>
</select>
```

```js
$("#firstDropDown").on('change', function(e) {
    var loc_id = e.target.value;
    $.get('my/url/', function(data) {
        // success data
        $('#secondtDropDown').empty();
        $.each(data.list, function(index, eObj){
            $('#secondtDropDown').append('<option value=' + eObj.id + '>' + eObj.first_name + ' ' + eObj.last_name + '</option>');
        });
    });
});
```

However, when I want to make these drop downs look nicer using `select-chosen` class, everything goes wrong. This class totally changes the HTML of my drop downs like this.

```
<select id="firstDropDown" class="select-chosen" name="firstDropDown" data-placeholder="Choose a ..." style="display: none;">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
</select>
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 100%;" title="" id="firstDropDown_chosen">
    <a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
        <span>Vlaue 1</span>
        <div><b></b></div>
    </a>
    <div class="chosen-drop">
       <div class="chosen-search">
          <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
       </div>
       <ul  class="chosen-results">
           <li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0">
               Value 1
           </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<select id="secondDropDown" class="select-chosen" name="Visitor_user_id" style="display: none;">
    <option value="71">Andrew Simond</option>
</select>
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 100%;" title="" id="secondDropDown_chosen">
    <a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
        <span>Value 1</span>
        <div><b></b></div>
    </a>
    <div class="chosen-drop">
        <div class="chosen-search">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <ul class="chosen-results">
            <li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0">Andrew Simond</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">Value 1</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">Value 2</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">Value 3</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4">Value 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Now my question is that how can I handle all this odd (for me, not for all of you) looking HTML to update the dropdown from an ajax request as I did in above code snippet?

Comment: The extra HTML is due to the templates that the plugin uses to replace the native `select` elements to add the required styling. If you need to update the options of the select after instantiating the plugin, check the available methods in its documentation. There should be something which allows you to update/refresh them dynamically.

Comment: Can you plz help me how to update the drop down? I've spent lot of my time but couldn't find any thing useful.

Answer (score 0):

Once we set the value. we have to refresh the select box.

```
$('select').val(123);
$('select').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

I hope this will work.